# Diameter of a graph such that given independent vertices u, v, d(u) + d(v) ≥ n.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

given my continuous struggle with proofs on graph theory, I come with another problem I do not know how to approach.

Given a graph G = (V, E) such that for any two non-neighboring vertices
u, v ∈ V , d(u) + d(v) ≥ n. (n being the number of vertices)
1. Assuming G is not a clique, what is the diameter of such a graph?
2. Prove that in G there always exists a Hamiltonian cycle.

Thank you to any kind soul willing to help

Comment: You can always make more of an effort (that is, any effort at all) even if you don't know what to do. For example: for (1), have you tried drawing small examples of such graphs, and what is their diameter? for (2), what techniques do you know to find a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: I have indeed and it seems to me that in every case (that is for 4,5,6 vertices) the diameter is always 2. But I wouldn't know how to justify it. I assume induction can be used to generalise it to more vertices but its something I still struggle with

Comment: It is better if you add your attempts to the question to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that the diameter of this graph is always $2$, just take any two vertices $u$ and $v$ and look at the length $1$ and length $2$ paths between them.

If there is an edge $uv$, they are at distance $1$ and everything is good.

If there is no edge $uv$, then the condition $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n$ applies. There are $n-2$ different possible length $2$ paths from $u$ to $v$, using the edges $ux$ and $xv$ for some third vertex $x$. Now apply the pigeonhole principle:

- There are at least $n$ edges incident to $u$ or to $v$.
- There are $n-2$ vertices $x \ne u,v$ in the graph.
- So at least $2$ of the $n$ edges must be incident to the same vertex $x$.

This gives us a path $ux, xv$ of length $2$.

You see that this proof actually works if we have $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n-1$. We need $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n$ for non-adjacent $u$ and $v$ for the second part of your question, which is just the statement of [Ore's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem).